# MessengerInstance.Send raises System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException on non-dev machines

Tags: mvvm-light

My application is raising the following exception:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

When using MessengerInstance.Send from our home view.  The code that raises the exception is [here](https://github.com/matortheeternal/mod-analyzer/blob/master/ModAnalyzer/ViewModels/HomeViewModel.cs#L24-L35).

The exception does not occur on our development machines, it only occurs on the machines of our testers.  At first the exception would crash the application, when I added the exception handler the exception would be caught the first time a user selected an archive to analyze and the application would work (not throwing an exception) with any archives selected afterwards.

You may be able to recreate this behavior with the [latest release](https://github.com/matortheeternal/mod-analyzer/releases) from GitHub, which does not have the try-except block (so the application will crash when an archive is selected).

We don't really know what's causing this bug, it's pretty odd.  Our next step in testing is to send an entire package (with pdb, xml, and manifest files) to our testers to see if that changes anything.  Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: Update: Sending everything from our build folder to our testers made no difference in the results.

Comment: We're trying to have our testers install .NET Framework 4.5.2 and the developer pack to see if that makes a difference.